# Add currency symbol to my value that is outputted in a php array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I’ve got the following answer from a question I posted in WordPress Stack Exchange, but how do I show the currency symbol (£) before the value of $givingback_details_funds?

```
$giving_back = array();

$givingback_details_funds = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'givingback_details_funds', true );

if ( $givingback_details_funds ) {
$giving_back[] = $givingback_details_funds;
}

$givingback_details_days = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'givingback_details_days', true );

if ( $givingback_details_days ) {
$giving_back[] = _n( 'one working day', $givingback_details_days. ' working days', $givingback_details_days );
}

if ( ! empty( $giving_back ) ) {
echo 'the team donated' . implode( ' and ', $giving_back );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$giving_back[] = '£ '.$givingback_details_funds;`

Comment: Thank you Hamza, I can't mark your comment as the answer but it's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you even mean? so you cant use this?

```
$giving_back = array();

$givingback_details_funds = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'givingback_details_funds', true );

if ( $givingback_details_funds ) {
$giving_back[] = $givingback_details_funds;
}

$givingback_details_days = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'givingback_details_days', true );

if ( $givingback_details_days ) {
$giving_back[] = _n( 'one working day', $givingback_details_days. ' working days', $givingback_details_days );
}

if ( ! empty( $giving_back ) ) {
echo 'the team donated £' . implode( ' and £', $giving_back );
}
```

or this: **EDITED**

```
$giving_back = array();

$givingback_details_funds = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'givingback_details_funds', true );

if ( $givingback_details_funds ) {
$giving_back[] = $givingback_details_funds;
}

$givingback_details_days = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'givingback_details_days', true );

if ( $givingback_details_days ) {
$giving_back[] = _n( 'one working day', $givingback_details_days. ' working days', $givingback_details_days );
}

$giving_back2 = array_map("mapper",$giving_back);

if ( ! empty( $giving_back2 ) ) {
echo 'the team donated' . implode( ' and ', $giving_back2 );
}
function mapper($a){
   return '£'.$a;
}
```

Or if you are not gonna use the $giving_back again like for only having numbers you can also use this. as  – Hamza Abdaoui said.

```
$giving_back[] = '£ '.$givingback_details_funds;
```

Comment: I can't use your first answer because I only want the £ symbol to show if there is a value for $givingback_details_funds. I'm not sure what's going on in the second answer, but it has an error in it and returns a white page.

Comment: can you use this? `if ( ! empty( $giving_back ) ) {
echo 'the team donated '.(!empty($giving_back)?'£':'nothing') . implode( ' and £', $giving_back );
}`

Comment: what you want to show in case `$giving_back` was empty? the team donated £0 ?

Comment: Thank you, this worked:$giving_back[] = '£ '.$givingback_details_funds;

Comment: Regarding this: "what you want to show in case $giving_back was empty? the team donated £0 ?" I want to show nothing.

Comment: if you mean '' from nothing use this: `if ( ! empty( $giving_back ) ) { echo 'the team donated '.(!empty($giving_back)?'£':'') . implode( ' and £', $giving_back ); } ` or if noting means: 'nothing' use this: `if ( ! empty( $giving_back ) ) { echo 'the team donated '.(!empty($giving_back)?'£':'nothing') . implode( ' and £', $giving_back ); } `